# SelectlistItem selected = true problem

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm having problems with getting selected items in a select-list.

```
Product product = _pr.GetProducts().ByProductID(productID).First();
        product.Categories.Load();
        ICollection<Category> allCategories = _cr.GetCategories().ToList();

        List<SelectListItem> Categories = (from category in allCategories
                                           select
                                           new SelectListItem
                                           {
                                               Selected = product.Categories.Contains(category),
                                               Value = category.CategoryID.ToString(),
                                               Text = category.Categoryname
                                           }).ToList();
```

Categories return 4 items, and selected is false on all....... If I hover "product.Categories" there are 3 items there, which is correct.... but somehow it doesnt get set to true.

What might be wrong?
/M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overload of `Contains()` that you're using is going to use the default object comparison, which will only match the exact same instance unless you've overridden `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()`. One option is to create a custom `CategoryEqualityComparer` and pass it to [this overload of `Contains()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118.aspx). Or, you could just join the categories on ID:

```
Product product = _pr.GetProducts().ByProductID(productID).First();
product.Categories.Load();
ICollection<Category> allCategories = _cr.GetCategories().ToList();

List<SelectListItem> Categories = (
    from category in allCategories
    join pc in product.Categories
      on category.CategoryID equals pc.CategoryID into j
    select
    new SelectListItem
    {
        Selected = j.Any(),
        Value = category.CategoryID.ToString(),
        Text = category.Categoryname
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: damn .. you beat me by 14 seconds :)

Answer (score 0):

I see that you set 'allCategories' to a _cr.GetCategories collection - are you sure the product contains categories from that collection?  It looks like your Categories field doesn't contain any of the product categories.  Can you post what is in each collection?

Comment: I'm not sure, I don't think so.  You could use a foreach() loop and just print them to the Console.